# Is there an equivalent to SQL Server's SET NOCOUNT in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql-server

Does MySQL have an equivalent to SQL Server's `SET NOCOUNT ON` statement?

Answer (score 10):

The `SET NOCOUNT ON` [stops the message indicating the number of rows affected by a Transact-SQL statement from being returned as part of the results](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa259204(SQL.80).aspx).

MySQL doesn't report the number of rows affected by a query, therefore there's no such function.

You *can* if you like find out about the number of affected rows using the [ROW_COUNT()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_row-count) function, right after your query:

```
DELETE FROM mytable WHERE name="John";
SELECT ROW_COUNT();
```

Comment: I am not sure why you saying that but mysql does count and report the number of rows.

Comment: Has anyone resolved this yet? I can't get around it myself.

Answer (score 1):

There is no equivalent as far as I am aware.

Comment: Speed of SQL transactions on a slow connection. If an "ack" is required for every query, it can slow down SQL performance. Or am I wrong about this?

Answer (score -1):

In php use:

do{} while ($r->nextRowset());

```
//bla bla
$rr->bindParam(1,$var,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$rr->execute();
do{ var_dump($rr->fetch());} while ($rr->nextRowset());
```